# Symfony2 and ODBC support

Tags: php, database, symfony, odbc, database-connection

We are on the early stage of developing an application and we're using Symfony2 framework to do the job. We need to connect to Oracle database. It works great with oci8 driver, but unfortunately it seems that our company doesn't support oci8 and can't install that PHP extension on the production servers. They recommended using ODBC for PHP instead.

Well... now we're stuck. Is there any good way for Symfony 2.8 to work with ODBC? Is this somehow supported? Did anybody actually try this setup?

Comment: You can configure the DBAL layer of Doctrine to use ODBC, look here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#pdo-oci-oci8

Comment: there is no mention of odbc connection in doctrine dbal

Comment: you could use pdo class to connect to odbc database like this: $conn = new PDO("odbc:DSN_NAME") ;

Comment: We could use that, but we're loosing ORM support that way, right?

Comment: I believe so since there are no drivers for odbc in doctrine.